# PDFBox - An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly

Tags: java, pdfbox

We are using the pdfbox library 2.x to manipulate the pdf operations. Among those in one operation, I have to remove the selected image from the page. It works properly. But when I open the modified document it shows a warning message:
`An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly.` and it is as below:

Warning Message Popup:
[image: Warning Message Popup]

Below is the code to remove an image from the page:

```
PDResources resources = copyResources(page);
COSDictionary pageObjects = (COSDictionary) resources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT);
COSDictionary newObjects = new COSDictionary();

Set<String> imageNames = findImageNames(page);
Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
for (COSName xObjectName : xObjectNames) {
    System.out.println(xObjectName);
    if (resources.isImageXObject(xObjectName)) {
        Boolean used = imageNames.contains(xObjectName);
        if (used) {
            newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
        } else {
             System.out.println("Found unused image: name={}"+xObjectName.getName());
        }
    } else {
        newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
    }
}
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT, newObjects);
page.setResources(resources);
```

Please help me if I'm missing anything with this code and also let me know if further information required.

**Below code remove the specific image by metadata:**

```
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
parser.parse();

List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++) {
    Object token = tokens.get( j );
    if(token instanceof COSName) {
    COSName cosname = (COSName) token;
    PDXObject o = resources.getXObject(cosname);
    

    if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject) o;
            DomXmpParser xmpParser = new DomXmpParser();
            XMPMetadata xmpMetadata = xmpParser.parse(pdImageXObject.getMetadata().toByteArray());
            if(imgUniqueId.equals(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle())) {
                newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
        newTokens.add(token);
    }
    
    PDStream newContents = new PDStream( document );
    OutputStream outputStream = newContents.createOutputStream();
    ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter( outputStream );
    writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
    outputStream.close();
    newContents.addCompression();
    page.setContents(newContents);
```

Comment: You need to correct the page content stream too

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thanks for your response. I have just started getting into PDFBox. So Could you please tell me what changes should be done in the existing code for that? It would help.

Comment: See the RemoveAllText.java example in the source code download; here, what you need to search and remove instead is "/name Do". (Sorry I'm somewhat busy now)  Also use PDFDebugger to look at your content stream.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Yes I checked that text removal example. But what if I have two images and both match the condition of - **operator.getName().equals("Do")**. In this case, both images will be removed. Please have your time and help me with this.

Comment: Yes an image with a name can be used twice or more, and then both identical images would be removed. You need to check the name too, not just "Do".

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr But while looping tokens how do we get the name of a specific token(As image name in mine case)? Added my piece of code in question summary. Please guide me on what changes need to be done in my code.

Comment: `newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1)` is the name. You are removing it and skipping adding "Do" to the target token list, which is correct. Is the error message from Adobe still appearing or not? "how do we get the name of a specific token" seems like a different question. Besides, I thought you knew which image to remove, you wrote "I have to remove the selected image from the page. It works properly."

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Now, I am able to remove a specific image from the content stream and it does not show that error(code added in question summary). But after that, if I draw another image on that page then it is not being added thereafter saving the document. It seems like the page stream is closing while removing a specific image and that is the reason. Please suggest me, even your words are very useful to me.
Even it is not working when we load that document(after removed images) again.

Comment: "But after that, if I draw another image on that page then it is not being added thereafter saving the document." - that wasn't the question. Your original question was about that weird message, it is solved and has been answered in the comment. You should now put the "winning" code as an answer yourself and create a new question for "I draw another image on that page then it is not being added thereafter saving the document" and include the code you used.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr apologies for that. I will do the same and moving forward will take care of this.